How to profile NodeJS files imports
In one of our applications, we need to optimize the startup time.
Is there a way to profile a Node.js application to see which files are being imported and how long these imports take?
Ideally, it would show a dependency import tree so that we can decide where to optimize these imports through dynamic importing.
We tried the --prof and --prof-process profiling options available in Node.js, but there is no profiling information from the application startup time.
Thanks for any suggestions
Edited:
This is our tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020", 
    "lib": ["es2023"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "@/*" : ["./*"]
    },                         
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
    ], 
    "resolveJsonModule": true, 
    "sourceMap": true,   
    "outDir": "./build", 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  },
}

and package.json:
{
  "type": "module",
  ...
}


Which module system are you using?

typescript  configured to generate ES2020 target, lib es2023, module ESNext, moduleResolution Node

Have you tried clinic.js ?

I saw it before but I don't think it's usable for my issue. Clinic looks great but I think it's for profiling the running app, not the app start.
